# What counts as an "other" weapon in Halo 4's stat tracking?

Tags: halo-4

I was checking out my stats over at Halowaypoint.com and came across a rather peculiar statistic. At the very bottom of my weapon stats for the slayer games I've played it says I have been killed by "other" one time. Does anyone have any idea what counts as an "other" weapon? I'd like to know because it could lead to some funny/weird ways to try and get kills for entertainment value, lol.

Relevant Screencap: [image]
Relevant URL: https://app.halowaypoint.com/en-us/Halo4/Klokworkk/wargames/ (not sure if that'll work for people that aren't me. Someone let me know if it is working for them?)

Comment: Nobody but you can see your wargames stats. I can only see your service record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my own service record and what I remember of the few times that I played Flood, the "Other" weapon is the map itself. So falling to your death without getting shot, and I'm not sure what else would.

Comment: From what I remember of Halo 3 and Reach this is mostly correct. Other things that used to count as other included props that were sent flying from explosions (not exploding props, which credit a kill, but things like traffic cones and the like) fast enough to kill, being crushed by a spawning vehicle and things like that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I remember too. I kind of meant to implicitly include it in "the map itself", but it's a good point about the exploding props. I'm not even sure if you *can* be killed by spawning vehicles in Halo 4 War Games.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the other is not referring to suicides. it is what are called environment kills. these kills consist of things on the map killing you, such as a crate or even a cone killing you because it was shot across the map by an explosion that happened on/around that item. you probably got taken out by something on the map. for examples you could go on youtube or google and look up killer halo street cone. there are some pretty crazy kills like that.